# Jenkins Bitbucket Notifier does not notify when using pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, bcbsn

I have this JenkinsFile

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    node {
      label 'SERVER'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Notificando Inicio do Job') {
      steps {        
        bitbucketStatusNotify buildState: 'INPROGRESS'
      }
    }
    stage('Restore') {
      steps {
        powershell(script: 'dotnet restore', returnStatus: false)
      }
    }
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        powershell(script: 'dotnet build ./path', returnStatus: false)
      }
    }
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        powershell(script: 'dotnet test ./path', returnStatus: false)
      }
    }
  }
  post{
      always{
        echo "Finalizando Build..."
      }
      success{
        bitbucketStatusNotify buildState: 'SUCCESS'
      }
      failure{        
        bitbucketStatusNotify buildState: 'FAILED'        
      }
  }
}
```

My desire is notify Bitbucket with build status.

This Jenkinsfile works perfectly ok when I run from an Multi-Branch pipeline, but, when I use it with a simple pipeline, it does not work.

Then, I go to the jenkins logs, and the only this related is...
But, from [plugin doc](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-build-status-notifier-plugin), these parameters are not mandatory.

[image]

My oauth client is correctly configured on bitbucket.

[image]

And on my jenkins, I have the credentials ok;

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?
How can I make it happen?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes. The problem was with Git Plugin. We are working with Git Plugin version 3.9.2